# Objects in ArrayList not retaining their type using generics

Tags: java, generics, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have a two-dimensional `ArrayList` to store `Block` objects to use later. However, it won't let me call `Block` methods on the objects when I get them by their index in the list. Here is the code where I initialize the list:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> col = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

for(int column = 0; column < SIZE; column++) {
        // Add a row of block objects
        col.add(new ArrayList<Block>());

        // Populate the row
        for(int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
            col.get(column).add(new Block());
            grid.add((Block) col.get(column).get(row));
        }
}
```

The problem seems to be that when I go to add the block to the `grid` (a JPanel), it won't compile unless I cast the object back to a `Block`. In other words, `grid.add(col.get(column).get(row))`
won't work. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need it to be

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Block>> col = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Block>>();
```

When you have just `ArrayList<ArrayList>` the get's would look like this

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> col = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList list = col.get(i);
Object obj = list.get(j);
```

Since `list` is an ArrayList with no type it will always return an Object.

If you have it as `ArrayList<ArrayList<Block>>` it would look like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Block>> col = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Block>>();
ArrayList<Block> list = col.get(i);
Block obj = list.get(j);
```